# Intellij idea не работает. Не знаю в чем проблема

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я создал проект и после его сохранения и загрузки он перестал видеть директории и в том числе класс "main"... Т.к. я недавно осваиваю программирование на языке java не могу описать суть проблемы, но могу дать скачать проект с github. Буду очень благодарен ведь это проблема преследует меня уже давно.https://github.com/gordod3/HomeWork2.2.
[image]

Comment: сборщик имеется?

Comment: В Event Log выдает какие нибудь ошибки? Попробуйте просто с папки перетенуть файлы ide

Comment: это не поможет, борюсь с той же ошибкой

Comment: @Artur Vartanyan ссылка на проект не робочая

Comment: я уже понял, просто у меня самого часто такое встречается во время клонирования. Наверно, это из-за новой версии Idea.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно помогал такой способ

1. закрыть idea
2. удалить папку .idea
3. запустить idea
4. нажать на импорт и импортировать проект заново

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что у тебя неправильная структура папок, нужно выделить папку src(исходников) и нажать правой кнопкой Mark Directory  as Source root
или в проекте мавен указать